# Cannot resolve FragmentStatePagerAdapter in import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing error like `fragmentstatepageradapter` cannot be resolved. I have imported the following:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

I also tried:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
```

Here is my complete code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new JavaFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PhpFragment();
            case 2:
                return new DotnetFragment();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Here is ,y graddle.build code:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aappen.com.buddiesnew"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar')
compile files('libs/ePOS-Print.jar')
compile files('libs/printer-lib.jar')
compile files('libs/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar')
compile files('libs/velocity-1.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm-server.jar')
compile files('libs/annotations.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
```

}

Comment: remove this `import android.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. You are using the one from support library

Comment: even after importing this also "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter; "i am getting same error..Is this the problem of version of studio?

Comment: can you post your app's build.gradle file. See if you have support library there

Comment: I just uploaded gradle.build code..Please checkout

Comment: 23.1.1 is the latest. use that

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing with the `app.FragmentPagerAdapter` and `support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`

Clear `Android.app.Fragment` and

use only

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the dependency of app gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'
```

Just make sure that the version number is same to that of other support libraries.